# random of sample of more than you plan to use?

Tags: sampling

My client is asking me to randomly sample 20 clusters when they only plan to use 10.  They are doing this in case something happens and some cannot participate.

I'm thinking this is no longer a random sample. Should I just call this a convenience sample or does it have still have some desirable properties of randomness.

My main question is what to call it?

Comment: Why not sample randomly?  What would be nonrandom about this sample of 20 clusters?

Comment: Maybe its fine, that is why I'm asking. I was concerned about them only using 10 of the 20 that were randomly sampled. Does that matter?

Comment: It can matter, depending on how those 10 are chosen.  In field studies, where there may be a possibility that planned samples cannot be collected, the design often calls for a larger sample than needed.  How that sample is taken and how the data are analyzed depend on the reasons observations cannot be made: it's a "missingness" problem.

Comment: The 10 will be half of the random sample of 20.  I think it does matter and that this can't be called a random sample.  Half of the selected sample will have a 0 probability of making it into the study. the rest will have 20/N probability that should be 10/N.   Just looking for confirmation before making an incorrect statement.  Thanks.

Comment: If the half sample is selected randomly from the full sample, then the half sample is random.  One common solution in designing such studies is to select the 20 clusters randomly and to specify a random sequence for the sample.  In the field you attempt to observe all 20, but maybe it's possible only to observe 12 of them.  You take the first ten of those 12 that appear in the original list.  *Assuming* that missingness is independent of the observations, those ten are a simple random sample of the population.

Comment: In the field they will only attempt 10 total, even if it is possible to observe all 20 they only have the capacity for 10.  Do you have a reference for the random sequence?  I googled it and can't find it. Thank you.